# Can't play audio in voice channels, AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'play'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
vc = bot.get_channel(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
await vc.connect()
await vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source="assets/a.mp3"))
```

This code was working like 3 months ago, and now it doesn't because voice channel object (vc) has no attribute play. Any reason why it stopped working and how to fix it?

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Poco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Poco\Desktop\py\elevate\main.py", line 38, in play
    await vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source="assets/ass.mp3"))
AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'play'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Poco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Poco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Poco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'play'
```

I tried to use different vcs, servers, permissions but nothing has solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `AttributeError` typically means you have the wrong type of object. Like the error says, a `VoiceChannel` has no attribute `play`. If you look [the API docs for voice channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#voicechannel) you can indeed see there is no `play()` method there.

However, if you do a quick search through the docs, you will find the method on [VoiceClient](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient). So you need a instance of `VoiceClient` to use the play method. How do you get a instance of `VoiceClient`? The docs state clearly how to do this:

> You do not create these, you typically get them from e.g. VoiceChannel.connect().

If you look at [the docs for `VoiceChannel.connect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect) you see it states clearly:

> **Returns**
> A voice client that is fully connected to the voice server.

So all you need to do is actually save the return value. So replace this:

```
await vc.connect()
```

with this:

```
connection = await vc.connect()
```

Now you have a instance of the voice channel object. Now, instead of calling `play()` on the channel, which has no method named `play()`, call it on the `VoiceClient`, which does. Our instance of the `VoiceClient` is named "conenction", so we can do this:

```
await connection.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source="assets/a.mp3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
if voice and voice.is_connected:
    await voice.move_to(channel)
else:
    voice = await channel.connect()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.